# Writing None in a file using python

Tags: python, string, file-io, output, nonetype

I'm trying to put the output in a new file

```
with open('INFO', 'a') as x:
        x.write(main())
```

But I got this error

```
x.write(main())
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None
```

When I write

```
with open('INFO', 'a') as x:
        x.write(str(main()))
```

In the file I got only this

```
None
```

how can I fix it? plz help

Comment: What do you expect to be written in the file?

Comment: `main()` seems to return `None`. what are you actually try to write in the file?

Comment: what did you expect from main()? first you need to make sure main() returns what you expect.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I actually try to put the output of main() function but it do not work

Comment: @Shiping I can print the output but I can't write it in INFO file

Comment: with "output" do you mean the things that are `print`ed by main? without knowing what your main does (and more details in general) it will be hard to give a sensible answer...

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I can't write what is is main function

Comment: do you have discord I will explain there

Comment: @hiroprotagonist this is my discord username charonIV#1879

Comment: then you should come up with something that emulates what your main does and post it here. otherwise no one will be able to answer because it is very unclear what the question is. read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though `main()` does not return anything. This is normal Python behavior, make sure you added a `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Write function accepts a string as arguement i.e

```
with open('INFO', 'a') as x:
    x.write('Hello')
```

will write the string "Hello" to the INFO file.
The reason you're getting an error is because you're not passing a string as an argument but you're instead passing a function call that may not be returning a string. Make sure that the main function is returning an object of type string before passing it to the write function. You could opt to do this:

```
word = str(main())  #Ensuring a string is the main function returns a string
with open('INFO', 'a') as x:
    x.write(word)
```

Ensure that the main function has a return statement before passing it as an arguement.

Comment: I want to past the output of main() function

Comment: Make sure your main function has a return statement somewhere in its definition. If it doesn't have a return statement, then the main function will return None. And None can't be written to your file.